# jQuery: how to get a random number in filename

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I'm using the following code to get a html content file from a folder.

```
        $(window).bind('load', function() {
        $.ajax({

        url: "/folder/htmlcontent1.html",
        success: function (data) { $('.attach').append(data); },
        dataType: 'html'
        });
        });
```

I want to make it random and pick up a random file on every page load. The files will be named incrementally like "htmlcontent1,htmlcontent2". I wonder if it's possible to use Math.floor in the url path like this:

```
    var rand_no = Math.floor((3-1)*Math.random()) + 1;
    $.ajax({

    url: "/folder/htmlcontent' + rand_no + '.html",
    success: function (data) { $('.attach').append(data); },
    dataType: 'html'
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean you *wonder* ? Did you test ? Note that you have incoherent quotes.

Comment: url: "/folder/htmlcontent" + rand_no + ".html",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. But you must fix the quotes :

```
url: "/folder/htmlcontent" + rand_no + ".html",
```